# Importing an CSV and replacing all special characters (Umlauts)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to import a CSV and want to change all special characters in the CSV. 
e.g. ö -> oe ; ü -> ue ; etc.
and than export all of this back to the csv

Content of CSV Example:

```
101|49|201907020|DE|bla|Schütze|Yayjay|||info|info2||||||||DE||||||||
101|49|201907020|DE|bla|Götther|Yayway|||info|info2||||||||DE||||||||
101|49|201907020|DE|bla|blub|Yayway|||info|info2||||||||DE||||||||
```

Tried different ways.

1. using the "-replace" command

   $line = $line -replace 'ü', 'ue'
2. using the ".replace" command

   $line = $line.Replace('ö','oe').Replace('ä','ae')

--

```
$importfile = "Path to CSV.csv"
$exportfile = "Path to Export.csv"
$Content = import-csv $importfile -Encoding UTF8 -Header A

$Content | Foreach-Object { 

    foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties)
    {

        [String]$line = $property.Value

        Write-host "Linie 1 $line" 
        $line = $line -replace 'ü', 'ue'

# Commented to see the different outputs
#$line1 = $line.Replace('ö','oe').Replace('ä','ae').Replace('ü','ue').Replace('ß','ss').Replace('Ö','Oe').Replace('Ü','Ue').Replace('Ä','Ae')
        Write-host "Linie 2 $line" 
    }
}
$Content
```

It is not replacing the special characters.

If I replace the $property.value with a string like "Bla|ü|" the script is replacing ü to ue.

Comment: What happens if you display the character retrieved from the csv file (e.g.: `Write-Host $property.Value`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first look, you don't have to use `Import-Csv` to work with text file. It depends on the task you are doing, but using `Get-Content` in this case looks more suitable as it reads a file as string array and not as dynamic objects array.

Also, remember, that `-replace` operator uses **regular expressions** as a pattern.
You need to escape special symbols and follow regexp syntax.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6

I was able to replace that special symbols using their unicode codes.

\uXXXX, where XXXX - code in hex.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference

```bsh
    $importfile = 'C:\TEMP\ps_1\src.txt'
    $Content = Get-Content $importfile
    $Content | ForEach-Object {
        foreach ($ch in $_.ToCharArray())
        {
            Write-Host "$($ch)[$([int]$ch)] " -NoNewline
        } 
        Write-Host

        Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host ($_ -replace 'ü', 'ue') -ForegroundColor Yellow # works if script and src.txt are saved in the same encoding
        Write-Host ($_ -replace "\u0413\u0458", 'ue') -ForegroundColor White # works if src.txt is in UTF8
        Write-Host ($_ -replace "\u00FC", 'ue') -ForegroundColor Gray # works if src.txt is in UTF8 with BOM
    }
```

UPD:

Case sensitive replace.
src.txt file has only one line:

```
--oöo--OÖO--uüu--UÜU--aäa--AÄA--bßb
```

```bsh
$importfile = 'C:\TEMP\ps_1\src.txt'
$Content = Get-Content $importfile

$replacePairs = @{
    "\u00FC" = 'ue'
    "\u00DC" = 'Ue'
    "\u00F6" = 'oe'
    "\u00D6" = "Oe"
    "\u00E4" = 'ae'
    "\u00C4" = 'Ae'
    "\u00DF" = 'ss'
}

$Content | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Green
    $resultLine = $_
    foreach($pair in $replacePairs.GetEnumerator())
    {
        Write-Host "`t$($pair.Key) $([char][Convert]::ToInt32(($pair.Key.Substring(4)), 16)) --> $($pair.Value)" -ForegroundColor Gray
        $resultLine = $resultLine -creplace $pair.Key, $pair.Value
        Write-Host $resultLine -ForegroundColor Gray
    }
    Write-Host $resultLine -ForegroundColor Yellow    
}
```

Comment: I understand your code, but still for me it doesn't work.
Tried also with Get-Content -Encoding UTF8, but still the same as in my example...

Comment: Try uncomment code piece and check what symbol codes do you read from the file, then replace that symbols with -replace using regexp syntax.
It's also matter in what encoding your script is saved. My one is saved in UTF8.

Comment: If I save 'Schütze' in txt file with in UTF8 encoding it'll be stored in 2 chars (1043 + 1112):
S = 83
c = 99
h = 104
Г = 1043
ј = 1112
t = 116
z = 122
e = 101

If I save it with UTF8 with BOM it'll be 1 char (252):
S = 83
c = 99
h = 104
ü = 252
t = 116
z = 122
e = 101

This is the possible reason why my example doesn't work in your case.

Comment: for me it shows this:
h +  =  + 104
ü +  =  + 252
t +  =  + 116

so I changed it to this: 
Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host ($_ -replace "\u0252", 'ue') -ForegroundColor White

But still it did not change to "ue"

Comment: That's because regexp syntax requires numbers in hex. 252 dec is FC hex. Try $_ -replace "\u00FC", 'ue' .
I've changed sample in my answer a bit.

Comment: So the yellow one is the only one which changed the input.

If I add "-Encoding UTF8" to the get-content the gray one (last) is changing. 

What do you think is better?

Comment: Last one looks more deterministic to me. You read in UTF8 with BOM and you replace in UTF8 with BOM.

Comment: So I updated the script accordingly. Changing all the umlauts we might have, but what is kind of strange is that it is changing "Ö" (so in capital letter) to "oe" (small letter). Already tried with "oe".toUpper() but no luck

Comment: Can you show the code? Just checked $_ -replace '\u00D6', 'OE' and the result was 'GOEtther'.

Comment: $_ -replace "\u00FC", 'ue' `
        -replace "\u00DC", 'Ue' `
        -replace "\u00F6", 'oe' `
        -replace "\u00D6", "Oe" `
        -replace "\u00E4", 'ae' `
        -replace "\u00C4", 'Ae' `
        -replace "\u00DF", 'ss'

Comment: It is really strange, I changed the order of the replace commands and now all of them are with big letters (e.g. Oe) even the small ö.
I really don't get why...

Comment: I guess, it's because case insensitive nature of string comparisons in PowerShell by default. It treats uppercase and lowercase letters in source string as a single char and you see the result of last -replace operation.
Try using -creplace operator for case sensitive operation.
I'll add one more code sample to my answer to illustrate it.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the hint I needed :)
It is working now with -creplace

Answer (score 0):

Reedited.  This is all you need.  Add more -replace as needed.  If you want, set-content could save to the same file, but that seems risky.  Unless the input file is utf8nobom, you don't need to specify the encoding.

```
(get-content file.csv) -replace 'ö','oe' -replace 'ü','ue' | set-content file2.csv
```

Comment: sadly this didn't help. 
The second Write-Host is also still with the umlaut, so I guess this "$_.a = $line " wouldn't help. The problem is that the replace command is somehow not working for me.